# A duplicate bin range was detected. Try increasing the bin range precision

Tags: r, weka, cfs, fselector

A little help wit this error ?

I get it when i am running CFS in R

Runnin code:

```
best_features<- cfs(Target~.,df)
```

where **df** is the dataset
and **Target** and **best_features** are self explanatory.

Error:

```
Error in .jcall("weka/filters/Filter", "Lweka/core/Instances;", "useFilter",  :  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A duplicate bin range was detected. Try increasing the bin range precision.
```

Comment: How many levels do you have in `Target`?

Comment: It has real values , if that's what you're asking.

Comment: How many different real values are there? What's the range?

Answer (score 0):

The "`A duplicate bin range was detected.`" error is thrown by `RWeka::Discretize` which many `FSelector` functions call internally. It occurs when data columns contain too many values that differ only by a small amount (because `Discretize` uses fixed point representation when naming bins).

The solution is to scale the data by a large factor:

```
numcols <- sapply(df, is.numeric)  # can be omitted if data is entirely numeric
df[numcols] <- df[numcols] * 1000  # try larger values if this is not enough

best_features <- cfs(Target~.,df)  # or anything else that uses FSelector
```